# Rename a folder stored in Amazon S3 using the AWS Java SDK v2?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I'm implementing an app which offers file storage in Amazon S3, while the user operates with normal *files & folders* concept.
In the backend I use the AWS Java SDK Version 2.

Do I have any way to rename/move an entire folder (thus recursively modifying it's content) ?

Or do I have to manually implement a recursive parsing and invoking copy+delete for each resource ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can rename the file directory, the full path is actually an object store key.

Answer (score 0):

In amazon S3 you don’t really have folders, it’s just a key.
So if you want to « rename a folder » unfortunately you have to move all your objects to another key.